# Scrapy change / update public IP via Proxy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am using Scrapy for crawling Google and I want to change my IP from code. I am getting same public IP as my local from output even though proxy in meta of response is getting changed. If I go to that VM and get a response from that site then it shows me VM's IP which is I am using in `request.meta['proxy'] = ip` but from code it only shows Local Public IP

This is my code.

middleware.py

```
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(('%s:%s' % (username, pass)).encode()).decode().replace('\n', '').strip()
    request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
    request.meta['proxy'] = ip
```

settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'tutorial.middlewares.RotateUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'tutorial.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
```

spider1.py

```
 request = scrapy.Request(url='http://checkip.dyndns.org/', callback=self.check_ip)

 def check_ip(self, response):
    print(response.meta)
    pub_ip = response.xpath('//body/text()').re('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+')[0]
    print("My public IP is: " + pub_ip)
```

Output:

```
{'proxy': 'http://51.162.81.60', 'download_timeout': 360.0, 'download_slot': 'checkip.dyndns.org', 'download_latency': 19.054762840270996}
My public IP is: 118.110.179.234
```

Comment: Tried using `request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = basic_auth_header(dlvmname, dlvmpass)` but that did not work as well

Comment: Can you check if the proxy server is running in your VM ?>

Comment: I checked http_proxy and https_proxy but they were empty. Is there any other way to check of proxy server is running?

Comment: One suggestion i have is, You can write a simple request script that will make the request to http://httpbin.org/ip and it will return the ip. From that if the IP is not similar to your VM's ip then Proxy is working. Else proxy is not running

Comment: I checked this link from VM and it is showing me same IP as VM's IP. So how do I proceed in this case?

Comment: then your proxy server is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184694/discussion-between-nikhil-r-and-backtrack).

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, the proxy ip needs to be ip of a proxy server as in a proxy server should be reachable at the ip provided by you. You can't simply assign any random ip to any request. If you want to rotate IP that is a different thing altogether.

Also just in case mention scheme(http, https) and port. Not sure whether scrapy falls back to any default if scheme and port is not mentioned.

Also, please see the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy).

Comment: I want to rotate IP eventually that is why I am trying to test it with one IP. I am using this IP of a VM. Not sure why it specifically needs IP of server.